# Files not caching

Tags: web-development, cache

We store our images on S3 and our performance has been incredibly slow.  This morning we turned on CloudFront in hopes that our performance would increase.  When I analyze our performance with Google's Dev Tools or YSlow, our site is still slow. Both tools recommend I set expire times so browsers cache the images. I looked in our *.htaccess* file, `mod_expires` is turned on with the following rules:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 Media: images, video, audio

  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Why are our images not being cached by the browser?

Comment: What actual response headers are your server sending and what values is it setting them to? i.e. Cache-Conrol, Date, ETag, etc...... You can use a tool like [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) to help you capture that data.

Comment: @Mike - I couldn't use Fiddler2 since I am on Mac but I did download Charles. This may sound crazy but the response header size was 0 bytes (the request header was 212bytes).  Does this make sense?

Comment: Install firebug to catch the headers response, works on mac just fine.

Comment: Why are you editing an htaccess file on your server when the images are all stored on S3?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the cache control headers using the S3 console as your Apache .htaccess only affects locally stored files.

Within the S3 console, go to the Properties -> Metadata section for each file you want to change
Add Cache-Control, Expires & Last-Modified headers with appropriate values